# Как правильнее установить eclipse для разных яп?

Tags: eclipse

Недавно открыл для себя такую IDE как Eclipse и мне не понятно, как лучше её использовать для разных яп. Допустим я хочу использовать java, c++, python, kotlin, scala и js. Как мне лучше поступить? Установить один экземпляр eclipse и установить туда все нужные мне яп? Или лучше установить три экземпляра eclipse ( для java, для c++, для js) и в eclipse для java установить kotlin и scala, а в eclipse для c++ установить python?

Какие могут быть проблемы от использования первого или второго варианта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих языков в Eclipse есть разные перспективы - виды интерфейса, между которыми можно переключаться. Так же Eclipse поддерживает работу с разными workspaces - (директориями, объединающими несколько проектов, с которыми вы хотите работать одновременно). То есть вы можете использовать один Eclipse со всеми нужными плагинами всех требуемых языков. Единственное, что вы должны проверить, что сам Eclipse, с таким количеством одновременно загруженых плагинов, не тормозит. Так же, в пользу одного Eclipse для всего, может быть требование работать с несколькими языками одновременно. Дело в том, что все ваши плагины устанавливаются поверх базовой части Eclipse, которая одна. Когда вы запускаете несколько разных вариантов Eclipse, каждый из них загружает эту базовую часть снова. То есть используя один Eclipse для всего вы можете сэкономить на ресурсах, в первую очередь на памяти.